# How to round only one corner of a button in JUCE C++?

Tags: c++, juce

Having a hard time to round a single corner because our Designer insists.

Current code...

```cpp
graphics.fillRoundedRectangle(bounds.toFloat(), cornerRadius);
```

Comment: Does the info [at this JUCE forum](https://forum.juce.com/t/bordered-and-rounded-buttons/16138) possibly help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [juce::Path::addRoundedRectangle()](https://docs.juce.com/develop/classPath.html#ae99d7f45ea1ba9481a82d9e8ac3b76ab) for this. Here is an example:

```
class RoundedButton : public juce::Button
{
public:
    explicit RoundedButton (const juce::String& buttonName) : Button (buttonName) {}

protected:
    void paintButton (
        juce::Graphics& g,
        [[maybe_unused]] bool shouldDrawButtonAsHighlighted,
        [[maybe_unused]] bool shouldDrawButtonAsDown) override
    {
        static constexpr float cornerSize = 10.f;

        juce::Path p;
        p.addRoundedRectangle (
            0,
            0,
            static_cast<float> (getWidth()),
            static_cast<float> (getHeight()),
            cornerSize,
            cornerSize,
            false,
            false,
            true, // Only curve bottom left
            false);

        g.setColour (juce::Colours::red);
        g.fillPath (p);
    }
};
```